# Text does not stay center aligned in game engine

Tags: game-engine, text-object

My text is aligned at right in the game engine even if I aligned it at center.

Here is my text:

[image: Text center]

These are the properties:

[image: Text align center]

And when the game is launched, it is aligned to right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One obvious thing would be to convert it to a mesh. I recommend you keep a copy of the original object. Select your text in object mode, then hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, and convert the text to a curve, then hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> again to convert the curve to a mesh.

Comment: Im a very begginer, can you show how to do this. Thanks.

Comment: First, know that this is not reversible. I recommend you keep a copy of the original object. Select your text in object mode, then hit alt + c, and convert the text to a curve, and then hit alt + c again to convert the curve to a mesh. (As said here: http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?62339-Converting-Text-to-Mesh).

Comment: This got auto flagged as low quality. Will you add more to your answer, to make it more useful. (As it is now it really is just a comment)

Comment: I think that all the required steps are here. The link is here only because this is based on a similar post on Blemderartists.

Comment: @user277143 Better :) Consider that this is not a forum. If the link goes down, then your answer is not useful. If you are interested, see this meta post for the key markup: http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/questions/524/what-case-should-letters-inside-kbd-tags-be